# Generalized motion equation - acceleration of an acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

Standard motion equations for movement of singular point within absolute space-time, looks like this:
$$
\vec{a} = const.
$$
$$
\vec{v_{T+Δt}} = \vec{v_{T}} + \vec{a} Δt
$$
$$
\vec{p_{T+Δt}} = \vec{p_{T}} + \vec{v_{T}}Δt + \frac{1}{2} \vec{a} Δt^2
$$

It is a system with constant acceleration $\vec{a}$ ($m s^{-2}$).

System with constant 2. level acceleration $\vec{b}$ ($m s^{-3}$) and dynamic 1. level acceleration $\vec{a_{T}}$ ($m s^{-2}$) should looks like this:

$$
\vec{b} = const.
$$
$$
\vec{a_{T+Δt}} = \vec{a_{T}} + \vec{b} Δt
$$
$$
\vec{v_{T+Δt}} = \vec{v_{T}} + \vec{a_{T}}Δt + \frac{1}{2} \vec{b} Δt^2
$$
$$
\vec{p_{T+Δt}} = \vec{p_{T}} + \vec{v_{T}}Δt + \frac{1}{2} \vec{a_{T}} Δt^2 + 
\frac{1}{6} \vec{b} Δt^3
$$
I want to generalize this process, but i am not sure about polynomial coefficients.
If i have system where N is level of an acceleration (top constant acceleration),
how final polynomial function for point position should looks like?
$$
\vec{X_{N}} = const.
$$
$$
\vec{X_{N-1 | T+Δt}} = \vec{X_{N-1 | T}} + \vec{X_{N}} Δt
$$
$$
\vec{X_{N-2 | T+Δt}} = \vec{X_{N-2 | T}} + \vec{X_{N-1 | T}}Δt + \frac{1}{2} \vec{X_{N}} Δt^2
$$
$$
...
$$
$$
\vec{p_{T+Δt}} = \vec{p_{T}} + \vec{X_{1|T}}Δt + \frac{1}{2} \vec{X_{2|T}} Δt^2 +
... + \frac{1}{???} \vec{X_{N-1 | T}} Δt^{N-1} + \frac{1}{???} \vec{X_{N}} Δt^N
$$
My guess is, that i need factorial there:
$$
\vec{p_{T+Δt}} = \vec{p_{T}} + \vec{X_{1|T}}Δt + \frac{1}{2} \vec{X_{2|T}} Δt^2 +
... + \frac{1}{!(N-1)} \vec{X_{N-1 | T}} Δt^{N-1} + \frac{1}{!N} \vec{X_{N}} Δt^N
$$

so is it like this?

Comment: Factorials are correct.  You can think of the general case as a [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) which only has a finite number of non-zero terms.